# Login button shows only my written code

Tags: php, html

i am trying to implement login system. I made simple login.php system and simple index.html but if i click on submit button it will show me just code. What i am doing wrong?

This is my login.pgp

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ei saanud andmebaasiga ühendust!");
    mysql_select_db("livestudy") or die("Ei leidnud andmebaasi!");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FORM users WHERE username='$username'"");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows!==0)
    {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
     {
     $dbusername = $row['username'];
     $dbpassword = $row['password'];
     }
     if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
     {
        echo "Sa oled sisse logitud!";
        @$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     }
     else
        echo "Siestatud parool on vale";

     }
     else
        die("Sisestatud kasutajat ei eksisteeri!");

     }
     else
       die("Palun sisesta kasutajanimi ja parool!");

?>
```

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><p>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><p>
<input type="submit">



</html>
```

Comment: Looks like your server isn't set up to run PHP.

Comment: Copy this code you wrote a " to much! `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FORM users WHERE username='$username'");`

Comment: Sidenote: `("SELECT * FORM users WHERE username='$username'"")` - should be `("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'")` it's **FROM** not **FORM** and an extra quote. Plus, do use proper bracing techniques. Btw, your entire code is prone to multiple attacks. It's just a matter of time before your site gets hit, if this is a LIVE site or plan on to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic html structure wouldn't be bad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>


    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><p>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><p>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Also you have a few little mistakes in your php so try this:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($username && $password) {
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Ei saanud andmebaasiga ühendust!");
        mysql_select_db("livestudy") or die("Ei leidnud andmebaasi!");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
             $dbusername = $row['username'];
             $dbpassword = $row['password'];
            }

            if(($username == $dbusername) && ($password == $dbpassword)) {
                echo "Sa oled sisse logitud!";
                @$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            } else
                echo "Siestatud parool on vale";

        } else
            die("Sisestatud kasutajat ei eksisteeri!");

    } else
        die("Palun sisesta kasutajanimi ja parool!");

?>
```

If it still not works then your server doesn't support php! OR you don't have the skript running on a web server.

If you don't have a Web Server installed look through this links, choose one and install it:

[Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

[Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/)

Comment: Thanks :D is saw it right now too

Comment: *"but if i click on submit button it will show me just code"* - I doubt this has anything to do with the real problem. The most likely problem is that OP is trying to run PHP from a web browser, without having a Web server installed such as Wamp, Mamp, Xampp etc. If it were installed, it would throw an error and not "show code".

Comment: I got it. Thank you guys! The only problem now is "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in " but i think i can resolve it on my own. Cheers! ;)

Comment: I resolved my other problem by adding this line at the start of the code: 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

Comment: @Tarvo you can Vote up or Accept answers that solved your problem, so that other people with the same problem find the answer faster that  helped you